# Exclude get-eventlog (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have a report that gets generated by a script in powershell, it reports to me the event-logs of multiple servers. I didn't make the script, my former colleague did this. I'm new to powershell and just started to learn a bit about it.

I want to exclude a Citrix error event (`EventID 110`) that doesn't do any harm. (has to do with Session Reliability)

`get-eventlog-log application-computername`

`$server -EntryType error-after $d |select eventid,machinename,entrytype, message, source, timegenerated | ConvertTo-Html`

`-Head $h -Title "Rapport Server eventlogs"  | out-file -append $Report`

Answer (score 0):

```
get-eventlog -log application -computername $server -EntryType error -after $d |select eventid,machinename,entrytype, message, source, timegenerated| where {$_.eventid -ne 110} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $h -Title "Rapport Server eventlogs" | out-file -append $Report
```